# awk command returns inconsistent result

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a script which performs several validations in a file.
One of the validation is to check if a line exceeds 95 characters (including spaces). If it does, it will return the line number/s where the line exceeds 95 characters. Below is the command used for the validation:

```
$(cat $FileName > $tempfile)
totalCharacters=$(awk '{print length($0);}' $tempFile | grep -vn [9][4])
if [[$totalCharacters != "" ]]; then
  totalCharacters=$(awk '{print length($0);}' $tempFile | grep -vn [9][4] | cut -d : -f1 | tr "\n" ",")
  echo "line too long"
  exit 1
fi
```

In the lower environment the code is working as expected. But in production, there are time that the validation returns the error "line too long" but does not return any line number. We just reran the script and it does not return any error.

I would like to know what could be wrong in the command used.
The previous developer who worked on this said that it could be an issue with the use of the awk command, but I am not sure since this is the first time I have encountered using the awk command.

Comment: What do you think `$(cat $FileName > $ tempfile)` is going to do?  I think it will concatenate the file named by `$FileName` with `tempfile` and place the output in a file `$`.  And then capture the standard output of that — fortunately the standard output is empty — and parse that output as a command and run it.  You don't need the `$(…)` and you probably want to use `cat "$FileName" > "$tempfile"` — though it isn't clear why you need a copy of the input to work with; you could apparently just use the original file.

Comment: Note that the `grep -vn [9][4]` command is odd; it is the same as `grep -vn 94` and searches for lines that do not contain '94' (outputting the line number and the matching text).  Note that this means lines of length `194`, `294`, `940`, `1945`, etc will all not be selected (as well as lines of length `94`).

Comment: sorry, I did not noticed that space before the tempFile when I write the code here, you are correct it should be $tempFile. The copy of the input is just probably for back up, it was like that when I got the script which was modified several times. For the grep -vn [9][4] , I did not know that it will not select those lines, what was explained to me is that the grep will check if the file has lines more that 94  characters.

Comment: Try to use cut'n'paste to copy code — retyping code just gives you extra chances to make extra mistakes.  It also means we can't be sure whether we're seeing the real problem or a typo that was made while creating the question.  No major harm done this time.  Please remember for next time.  (The `grep -vn [9][4]` voodoo incantation suggests that you should look askance at the shell coding skills of your predecessors — the evidence on display here is not reassuring.)

Comment: @Patrick `grep -vn [9][4]` means `print the line numbers and text of lines that do not contain the string "94"`. The whole script is buggy nonsense.

Comment: All the lines in the file has 94 characters (including spaces). However, there will be times wherein the line/s exceeds 94 characters and this is what the script needs to catch. Does this mean the command makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not well written.  All you need is:

```
awk 'length>94{print NR; f=1} END{exit f}' file
```

If there are lines longer than 94 chars, it will print the line numbers and the exit with status 1; otherwise the exit status will be 0 and no output will be generated.

Comment: I suppose if one wanted to be fancy and also output the length they could use something such as `{printf "l: %-6d c: %3d\n", NR, length; f=1}`...

Answer (score 0):

Your script should just be:

```
awk '
    length()>95 { printf "%s%d", (c++?",":""), NR }
    END { if (c) {print "line too long"; exit 1} }
' "$FileName"
```